# How to change the "power key" for ratpoison window manager

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, ratpoison

Using the ratpoison window manager, how could I remap the "power key" (which is by default Ctrl-T) to something like the Windows button?

I have created a configuration file already (`~/.ratpoisonrc`) and just need to know how to bind a different key.

Comment: Where did you hear it is called the "power key"?  I think you're talking about what is called the "escape key".

Comment: The name escaped me for a moment, so I just called it that because it is basically a precursor for any action carried out in the wm.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [ChangeEscapeKeyHOWTO](http://ratpoison.wxcvbn.org/cgi-bin/wiki.pl/ChangeEscapeKeyHOWTO) and [Enjoying More Screen Space with Ratpoison](http://www.ragingpenguin.us/2013/11/55-enjoying-more-screen-space-with-ratpoison/), I think putting

```
escape Super_L
```

in your `~/.ratpoisonrc` should do the trick.

Comment: I added that under `exec bindkeys` but to no avail. I rebooted, and the key was not changed. Then, I added `bind` before `escape Super_L` but it also was not changed.

Answer (score 2):

Question is old, but for anyone reading it:

```
escape grave

definekey top Insert readkey root

definekey root Insert link grave
```

This will effectively change C-t to the grave key. I don't know what the windows key is called.

Don't remember where I got this, but it works.